# Executing cucumber test from custom module in quarkus

Tags: cucumber, quarkus

I am trying to execute cucumber test from custom/another module than test however facing issue.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate CDIProvider
    at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.findAllProviders(CDI.java:121)
    at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.getCDIProvider(CDI.java:82)
    at javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI.current(CDI.java:64)
    at io.quarkiverse.cucumber.CucumberQuarkusTest$CdiObjectFactory.getInstance(CucumberQuarkusTest.java:184)
```

Not sure how to provide CDI to custom module. Any help on this would be appreciated.

I am able to execute cucumber test from test module however I want to separate it from JUnits.

The code is attached in Git issue:
https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-cucumber/issues/38

Comment: as commented here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58634854/175554 , your project having wrong classpath. added maven example to github

Comment: @ozkanpakdil, Thank you for providing updated example with Maven. Is it possible to achieve this with gradle?
Also https://stackoverflow.com/a/58634854/175554 talks about version mismatch due to explicitly adding version, didn't understand about classpath issue.

Comment: I tried with Gradle but couldn't manage to find correct way, classpath configuration is far more easy in maven 